# Can an adjective modify a verb? How to identify word preposition modifies?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, diagramming

No one in that family can sit still for five minutes.

Answer in textbook

[image: answer]

I've having a bit of trouble parsing the sentence.

1. What form does 'still' take in this sentence? Dictionary says 'still' used in this fashion is an adjective. But what (noun/pronoun?) is it modifying?
2. I would have thought the prepositional phrase "for five minutes" answered "to what extent" of the word 'still' but in the picture it is connected to the verb. Why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68480/discussion-on-question-by-aatrx-can-an-adjective-modify-a-verb-how-to-identify).